# Mostrar de los registros repetidos solo los que tengan la fecha más antigua en SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como lo mencione en la pregunta, me gustaría mostrar de mis registros repetidos, solo aquellos que tengan la fecha más antigua. Tengo entendido que con la función `MIN()` puedo resolver este problema y lo intenté, pero me sigue mostrando los registros repetidos.

Este es el Query que actualmente tengo, no se si tenga algún error y por eso no me lo muestra debidamente, y me gustaría pedir su apoyo para saber que puede ser el error que tenga:

```
;WITH cteMechanicals AS (
                    SELECT                  
                    h.workDayId,h.EmployeeName,t.clave,t.nombre_curso,
                    MAX(t.es_fecha_inicio) fecha_examen,c.fecha_valido_desde
                    FROM TableHeadCount h 
                    LEFT JOIN Temp_Rep065 t ON h.workDayId = t.emp_clave
                    LEFT JOIN @udvM12953_CoursesList c ON t.clave = c.cur_clave
                    WHERE workDayId IN (SELECT value 
                        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@dummy, ',')) 
                    GROUP BY h.workDayId,h.EmployeeName,t.clave,t.nombre_curso,c.fecha_valido_desde
                ),cteMechanicals2 AS (
                    select workDayId,EmployeeName,clave,nombre_curso,fecha_examen,
                    MIN(fecha_valido_desde) fecha_valida_desde
                    from cteMechanicals
                    GROUP BY workDayId,EmployeeName,clave,nombre_curso,fecha_examen
                )
                select * from cteMechanicals2
```

Cabe mencionar que en el primer `cte` del Query muestro de los datos repetidos solo aquellos con la fecha más reciente de la columna `es_fecha_inicio` de la tabla `Temp_Rep065`, y ahora de esos resultado quiero obtener de los registros repetidos aquellos que tengan la fecha más antigua de la columna `fecha_valido_desde`, y aquí es donde ya no me muestra correctamente la información.

Les dejo un ejemplo de la ejecución de mi query y lo que quisiera quitar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Considero que todos los campos y join son necesarios para entender como funciona, ya que el primer left join me sirve para determinar si existe el empleado en mi primer tabla y si no que lo muestre de mi segunda tabla, seguido de esto los resultados hasta ahí me mostrarán los registros de todos los cursos hechos del usuario, pero un usuario puede hacer varias veces un mismo curso por lo que con la función `MAX()` muestro solo un registro si el usuario llega a tener hecho más de una vez un curso por medio de la columna `es_fecha_inicio`, hasta aquí todo bien pero como pueden ver en el resultado de la imagen al hacer `left join` con la tabla temporal `@udvM12953_CoursesList` que esta contiene la información para saber desde cuando es valido el curso y algunos de estos cursos en mi tabla temporal estan repetidos con distintas fechas por lo que me muestra los dos registros con fechas distintas en mi resultado de mi query y de este resultado me gustaria mostrar solo el registro que tenga la fecha más antigua. Espero que con esta explicación puedan entender lo que quiero remover de mi consulta final.

Comment: Considero que esta pregunta no se puede responder en su forma actual, pues habría que conocer el esquema y explicar con exactitud qué se considera _un registro repetido_. Creo que sería mejor simplificar el problema y plantear un [mcve], quitando todos aquellos campos y _joins_ que no son esenciales en la consulta de ejemplo, para que se pueda entender claramente el concepto y la dificultad que tienes.

Comment: En la query *cteMechanicals2* no aparece la columna *duración*, y en la imagen si (por lo tanto la imagen se corresponde con otra query). En este caso la query *cteMechanicals2* te devuelve el resultado que buscás, el problema es que las filas 4 y 5 no están duplicadas, ya que tiene diferente *duración* . Si la información está duplicada en la tabla temporal de cursos, yo filtraría los cursos duplicados allí en lugar de en la query principal.